# NotAcceptable error when calling graph API workspace resource type from C#

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-calendar

I'm trying to to get a list of all workspaces in a tenant (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/workspace?view=graph-rest-beta) but I'm receiving an error I see no solution to. My graph service client appears to be correct since I can get a list of all users without issues, but getting all the workspaces fails with an unknown error.

What I'm trying to replicate: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/place-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#request

Creating graph client and attempting to get workspaces from place:

```
    public async Task<List<string>> GetWorkspacesAsync()
    {
        var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
        var workSpaceUrl = graphClient.Places.AppendSegmentToRequestUrl("microsoft.graph.workspace");
        var workSpaceRequest = await new GraphServicePlacesCollectionRequest(workSpaceUrl, graphClient, null).GetAsync();
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you're targeting the beta version. For more information take a look at [Use the Microsoft Graph SDKs with the beta API.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/use-beta?tabs=CS)

If the error persists, share the date, request-id and correlation-id. All are included in the inner error.